# Is is possible to mix use Obj-c @synchronized and swift GCD

Tags: swift, objective-c, synchronization, grand-central-dispatch

I need to do some synchronization. One side is written in @synchronized ojb-c. The other side need to be written in Swift.

Is is possible to mix use Obj-c @synchronized and Swift GCD

Comment: You could write a small function and try it. Objective-C are Swift are interoperable, much of UIKit was originally written in Objective-C and can be used with Swift. Post an example if you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that prevents you from doing so, however be advised that while GCD operates with queues (which constitutes multiple threads) `@synchronized` works with threads. It means that if your queue is concurrent, it's still able to operate while being paused by the `@synchronized` block. Consider the following implementation for a synchronised Objective-C method:

```
// Some Objective-C class implementation file
@implementation MyObjcClass


- (void)syncMethod {
    @synchronized (self) {
        NSLog(@"Date: %@", [NSDate date]);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 4];
    }
}

@end
```

And here is how it could be used inside of a Swift class:

```
// Some Swift class implementation file
let objcClass = MyObjcClass()
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "my_queue", attributes: .concurrent)
queue.async {
    objcClass.syncMethod()
}
queue.async {
    print("Date \(Date())")
}
```

While the first async block pauses the execution for the given thread, the second one is called immediately anyway (the hours differ because `NSLog` prints `NSDate` with respect to local timezone):

```
Objc Date: Wed Aug  3 19:53:28 2022
Swift Date 2022-08-03 16:53:28 +0000
```

Also avoid calling the synchronised methods in UI thread, it will make the app unresponsive if another thread is currently accessing the data, and you are still vulnerable to deadlocks when using serial queues.

Apart from that, it should work as expected

Comment: In @synchronized you pass an obj but in GCD you pass label to it.  Since I cannot pass the same obj or label, they will sync if the two methods are called from different thread.  How can I prevent this?

Comment: @Snowtown123 the label has nothing to do with the synchronisation, it's just a debugging information for you as programmer. `@synchronization` block ensures that only one thread can access a resource (in this case `objClass`) at a time. If you want multiple threads to access the resource, what is the point of synchronisation? My goal was to demonstrate that the synchronisation in fact works from within GCD queues, while you ask how to prevent it from working..